# Prestashop Backend Logout after Cloudflare setup

Tags: prestashop, backend, cloudflare

I have setup cloudflare for my prestashop website. In backend each time i refresh a page it points me to backend login page, it logges me out.

In customer account this behavior does not happen. If i login as a customer it works fine.

I have created a rule in cloudflare settings with url pattern matching my backend: example.com/admin123/*. No results, same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something to [restore the visitor IP](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200038166-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-to-my-server-logs-)?

Generally see this kind of behavior if you're restricting logins to particular IPs and/or the CMS relies on unique IPs to login.

Comment: i host my website on a VPS and don't have privileges to install apache modules